# Sum different elements of a list of lists using one dictionary (Python)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sum

I have this list of lists:

```
    [Racing, 100]
    [Crossi, 100]
    [Racing, 120]
    [Racing, 130]
    [Marcas, 105]
    [Marcas, 109]
    [Crossi, 130]
    [Crossi, 104]
```

I want the total sum for Racing, Marcas and Crossi. I want do it with a dictionary on python if it's possible. Like this:

```
    Brads{"Crossi": 334, "Marcas": 214, "Racing":350}
```

Is it possible do it with only one `for` loop?

Comment: You mean you have list like this list= [[Racing, 100]
    [Crossi, 100],
    [Racing, 120],
    [Racing, 130],
    [Marcas, 105],
    [Marcas, 109],
    [Crossi, 130],
    [Crossi, 104]]

Comment: Yes I want mean this @Ayoub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict
list_ = [['Racing', 100],['Crossi', 100],['Racing', 120],['Racing', 130],['Marcas', 105],['Marcas', 109],['Crossi', 130],['Crossi', 104]]
dic = defaultdict(int)
for i in list_:
    dic[i[0]] += i[1]
print(dic)
```

out:

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'Marcas': 214, 'Crossi': 334, 'Racing': 350})
```

setdefault:

```
list_ = [['Racing', 100],['Crossi', 100],['Racing', 120],['Racing', 130],['Marcas', 105],['Marcas', 109],['Crossi', 130],['Crossi', 104]]
d = {}
for k,v in list_:
    d[k] = d.setdefault(k,0) + v
print(d)
```

out:

```
{'Marcas': 214, 'Crossi': 334, 'Racing': 350}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for this

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = [['Racing', 100],
     ['Crossi', 100],
     ['Racing', 120],
     ['Racing', 130],
     ['Marcas', 105],
     ['Marcas', 109],
     ['Crossi', 130],
     ['Crossi', 104]]

d = defaultdict(int)
for key, value in l:
    d[key] += value
```

Output of `print(d)`

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'Marcas': 214, 'Racing': 350, 'Crossi': 334})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
list_of_list = [
    ['Racing', 100],
    ['Crossi', 100],
    ['Racing', 120],
    ['Racing', 130],
    ['Marcas', 105],
    ['Marcas', 109],
    ['Crossi', 130],
    ['Crossi', 104]
]

people = {}

for selected_list in list_of_list:
    name = selected_list[0]
    if name in people:
        people[name] += selected_list[1]
    else:
        people[name] = selected_list[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Without importing *collections*, you may get the same behavior using [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) as:

```
my_dict = {}
for k, v in l:
    my_dict[k] = my_dict.get(k, 0) + v  # Here `my_dict.get(k)` will return the value
                                        # if `k` key is found, else will return 0
# Final content of `my_dict`:
# {'Racing': 350, 
#  'Marcas': 214, 
#  'Crossi': 334}
```

where `l` is the list mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

With more iteration on the list you can solve the problem in an one-line way.

```
l = [['Racing', 100], ['Crossi', 100], ['Racing', 120], ['Racing', 130],
     ['Marcas', 105], ['Marcas', 109], ['Crossi', 130], ['Crossi', 104]]

print dict((el[0], sum(v for k, v in l if k == el[0])) for el in l)
```

Comment: I wouldn't say this is more pythonic. This solution is `O(N^2)` whereas all other solutions posted above are `O(NlogN)`